# PHP - String gets chopped after nbsp character

Tags: php, javascript, post

I'm having a hard time using a combination of TinyMCE, Ajax and PHP Post to an ExpressionEngine database. The TinyMCE area collects the data from my database when the website loads, and I can edit it with rich text.

However, when I save these changes using ajax and POST to PHP, the string gets chopped off whenever the string contains `&nbsp;`. I haven't tried any other special characters, but it accepts `<p>` and `<h1>`

PHP code looks like this:

```
$tinyMCEData = $_POST['tinyMCEData'];
```

And when I echo this out, it's chopped off at this point. I've tried to replace the nbsp before it's sent off via Ajax, but I've no luck yet. I don't really care if there's a nbsp in there either, as long as it's accepted.

I've also tried htmlentities, like this:

```
$tinyMCEData = htmlentities($_POST['tinyMCEData']);
```

No luck there either. So why is this happening? I'm guessing there's a reason for this. Any help much appreciated!

Edit: My case looks exactly like the example from this question:
[TinyMCE + Jquery + PHP + AJAX Special chars issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863560/tinymce-jquery-php-ajax-special-chars-issue)

Only the bottom two screenshots of the alert boxes. All I have in my tinyMCE editor are more than once space in the text.

Edit2: Here's what the javascript looks like:

```
var tinyMCEData = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
var pars = 'tinyMCEData=' + tinyMCEData;

var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url, {
   method: 'post',
   postBody: 'pars,
   onSuccess: success,
   onFailure: failure
});
```

At this point, the data that's being sent looks like this for example:

```
<p>One two &nbsp;three &nbsp; four</p>
```

What the value is after php post:

```
<p>One two
```

Comment: Sounds like you are building the AJAX query's body as string and forgo to escape the `&` chars. Could you submit the javascript part where you are sending the request to the backend?

Comment: what does your data look like b4 its sent to your PHP? It looks like the errors is upstream of your PHP code

Comment: Just edited my post to answer your questions. I'm sending a lot more than one field at a time. But only this TinyMCE area needs to be rich text

Comment: That first of yours complex857 got me on the right track :) Escape the string. var tinyMCEData = escape(tinyMCEData); seemed to work!

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntac error:

```
var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url, {
   method: 'post',
   postBody: 'pars,
   onSuccess: success,
   onFailure: failure
});
```

shoud be

```
var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url, {
   method: 'post',
   postBody: pars,
   onSuccess: success,
   onFailure: failure
});
```

also, are success and failure defined as functions?

Comment: Sorry, the syntax error was just my mistake when pasting the code. And yes, the success and failure functions are defined. Just didn't bother adding them here, since they only output some alert boxes right now. However, the problem was solved using the escape function that complex857 mentioned :) I love this place :)

Answer (score 0):

complex857 was right! I only had to escape the string before it was sent to POST.
Like this:

```
var tinyMCEData = escape(tinyMCEData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for those who still have an issue with this (And especially if you want to submit more details)...

I separated the text data from the other variables instead of using a datastring. Then make sure one of the variables contains your text

```
data: {var1: var1,
       var2: var2,
       var3: var3}
```