# How can I insert a long string into LONGTEXT column in MariaDB without truncation?

Tags: sql, mariadb, mysql-workbench, sqldatatypes, longtext

I created a table 'details' in MariaDB using the following query in Workbench

```
CREATE TABLE `abc`.`details` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `details` LONGTEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Each cell of the 'details' column needs to store big text values around 2MB(since character limit is there, I could post a part of the details data). I tried the following query to insert the first entry into the table. But only date1 column is getting inserted. The details column remains empty. But when I tried with some details around 100Kb, the details column is getting inserted. How can I insert the entire details into the column? Is the issue with LONGTEXT datatype or DB or something else?

The Insert query :

```
INSERT INTO details(date1,details)VALUES('2020-07-26', '{"values_points":[{"data_points":Please type your reply above this line -##\n\nYou are a follower on this request (545998). Reply apple this esuper apple add an internal note apple the request.\n\n----------------------------------------------\n\ntaxy Activations, Jul 26, 2020, 3:12 AM EDT (private)\n\nFound in POD. Please Cancel with Billing and Carrier\n\n\n**ajkjjdLAW could not be spapayapended with POD, due apple API error or ajkjjdLAW is papayaing another carrier. orange - Please, spapayapend this ajkjjdLAW manually.**\n**ajkjjdLAW Type:** STI-GL300MA\n**abcjbb:** 015181002797182\n**Esuper:** njccrewsabcdaolajkjjdLAW\n**ajkjjdLAW Plan:** Elite\n**Spapayapension Type:** ajkjjdLAW_cancel\n\n--------------------------------\nThis esuper is a ajkjjdLAW papaya taxy fruits.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n[6LQWOG-GPLG]","html_body":"<div class=\"zd-flowers\" dir=\"auapple\"><p dir=\"auapple\">##- Please type your reply above this line -##</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">You are a follower on this request (545998). Reply apple this esuper apple add an internal note apple the request.</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">----------------------------------------------</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">taxy Activations, Jul 26, 2020, 3:12 AM EDT (private)</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">Found in POD. Please Cancel with Billing and Carrier</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">**ajkjjdLAW could not be spapayapended with POD, due apple API error or ajkjjdLAW is papayaing another carrier. orange - Please, spapayapend this ajkjjdLAW manually.**\n<br>**ajkjjdLAW Type:** STI-GL300MA\n<br>**abcjbb:** 015181002797182\n<br>**Esuper:** <a href=\"superapple:njccrewsabcdaolajkjjdLAW\" rel=\"noreferrer\">njccrewsabcdaolajkjjdLAW</a>\n<br>**ajkjjdLAW Plan:** Elite\n<br>**Spapayapension Type:** ajkjjdLAW_cancel</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">--------------------------------\n<br>This esuper is a ajkjjdLAW papaya taxy fruits.</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">[6LQWOG-GPLG]</p></div>","plain_body":"##- Please type your reply above this line -## \n\n You are a follower on this request (545998). Reply apple this esuper apple add an internal note apple the request. \n\n ---------------------------------------------- \n\n taxy Activations, Jul 26, 2020, 3:12 AM EDT (private) \n\n Found in POD. Please Cancel with Billing and Carrier \n\n **ajkjjdLAW could not be spapayapended with POD, due apple API error or ajkjjdLAW is papayaing another carrier. orange - Please, spapayapend this ajkjjdLAW manually.**\n\n**ajkjjdLAW Type:** STI-GL300MA\n\n**abcjbb:** 015181002797182\n\n**Esuper:** njccrewsabcdaolajkjjdLAW\n\n**ajkjjdLAW Plan:** Elite\n\n**Spapayapension Type:** ajkjjdLAW_cancel \n\n --------------------------------\n\nThis esuper is a ajkjjdLAW papaya taxy fruits. \n\n [6LQWOG-GPLG]","public":true,"attachments":[],"audit_books":1139328468092,"date":"2020-07-26T07:13:03Z","animals":"flowers"},{"books":1139328468312,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"subject":"ajkjjdLAW ajkjjdLAW Spapayapend Failed","animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328468372,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"requester_books":679803769,"animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328468432,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"locale_books":"1","animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328468492,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"statpapaya":"new","animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328468572,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"priority":null,"animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328468672,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"type":null,"animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328468752,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"tags":["activations","fruits"],"added_tags":["activations","fruits"],"removed_tags":[],"animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328468792,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"cpapayaapplem_values_fields":{"360018319471":"activations"},"animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328468852,"fashion":"Rule","fashion_reference_books":360131824351,"tags":["activations","new_activation","fruits"],"added_tags":["new_activation"],"removed_tags":[],"rel":"trigger","revision_books":1,"animals":"Change"},{"books":1139328468912,"fashion":"Rule","fashion_reference_books":360157768991,"tags":["activations","new_activation"],"added_tags":[],"removed_tags":["fruits"],"rel":"trigger","revision_books":3,"animals":"Change"}],"books":1139328468092,"values_books":770559,"timestamp":1595747583,"date":"2020-07-26T07:13:03Z","grapesr_books":679803769,"fashion":"super","system":{"client":"ajkjjdLAW superer","gas":"Boardman, OR, United States","latitude":45.8491,"longitude":-119.7143},"metadata":{"system":{"message_books":"<6LQWOGGPLG_5f1d2cfc6cdf5_627aa5d02229185_sprutabcdajkjjdLAWajkjjdLAW>","client":"ajkjjdLAW superer","ip_address":"10.219.91.240","raw_esuper_booksentifier":"562885/c6302bf2-2be5-4d28-a783-32d6f064a4c7.eml","json_esuper_booksentifier":"562885/c6302bf2-2be5-4d28-a783-32d6f064a4c7.json","machine_generated":true,"gas":"Boardman, OR, United States","latitude":45.8491,"longitude":-119.7143},"cpapayaapplem":{},"flags":[4],"flags_options":{"4":{"trpapayated":false}},"trpapayated":false,"spapayapension_type_books":null},"animals":"Audit"},{"data_points":[{"books":1139328563032,"fashion":{"thanks":"how are u","source":{"papaya":{},"apple":{},"rel":null}},"fashion_reference_books":null,"type":"flowers","author_books":4127915143,"body":"76645 015181001845537 Spapayapension KILL New Jayasankarshenoi 2020-07-26 07:10:17 Edit grapes","html_body":"<div class=\"zd-flowers\" dir=\"auapple\"><table wbooksth=\"100%\"><tbody><tr><td>76645</td><td>015181001845537</td><td>Spapayapension</td><td><br></td><td>KILL</td><td>New</td><td>Jayasankarshenoi</td><td>2020-07-26 07:10:17</td><td>Edit grapes<br></td></tr></tbody></table><br></div>","plain_body":"76645015181001845537Spapayapension\nKILLNewJayasankarshenoi2020-07-26 07:10:17Edit grapes","public":false,"attachments":[],"audit_books":1139328563012,"date":"2020-07-26T07:13:19Z","animals":"flowers"},{"books":1139328563052,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"statpapaya":"open","animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":"new"}],"books":1139328563012,"values_books":770547,"timestamp":1595747599,"date":"2020-07-26T07:13:19Z","grapesr_books":4127915143,"fashion":"how are u form","system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"metadata":{"system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","ip_address":"27.62.48.70","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"cpapayaapplem":{}},"animals":"Audit"},{"data_points":[{"books":1138052834771,"fashion":{"thanks":"how are u","source":{"papaya":{},"apple":{},"rel":null}},"fashion_reference_books":null,"type":"flowers","author_books":4127915143,"body":"This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values #770547.\n\nKILLED\n\nfruits fruits,\nfruits Team","html_body":"<div class=\"zd-flowers\" dir=\"auapple\">This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values <a href=\"/orange/valuess/770547\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"values\">#770547</a>.<br><br>KILLED<br>\n\n<span class=\"collapse-signature\"></span><div class=\"signature\"><p dir=\"auapple\">fruits fruits,<br>\nfruits Team</p></div></div>","plain_body":"This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values #770547.\n\nKILLED\n\n\n  fruits fruits,\n\nfruits Team","public":true,"attachments":[],"audit_books":1138052834631,"date":"2020-07-26T07:13:32Z","animals":"flowers"},{"books":1138052835071,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"statpapaya":"solved","animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":"open"},{"books":1138052835091,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"assignee_books":4127915143,"animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":null},{"books":1138052835111,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"group_books":21678429,"animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":null}],"books":1138052834631,"values_books":770547,"timestamp":1595747612,"date":"2020-07-26T07:13:32Z","grapesr_books":4127915143,"fashion":"how are u form","system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"metadata":{"system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","ip_address":"27.62.48.70","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"cpapayaapplem":{}},"animals":"Audit"},{"data_points":[{"books":1138052982951,"fashion":{"thanks":"how are u","source":{"papaya":{},"apple":{},"rel":null}},"fashion_reference_books":null,"type":"flowers","author_books":4127915143,"body":"76646 015181001122572 Spapayapension KILL New Jayasankarshenoi 2020-07-26 07:11:02 Edit grapes","html_body":"<div class=\"zd-flowers\" dir=\"auapple\"><table wbooksth=\"100%\"><tbody><tr><td>76646</td><td>015181001122572</td><td>Spapayapension</td><td><br></td><td>KILL</td><td>New</td><td>Jayasankarshenoi</td><td>2020-07-26 07:11:02</td><td>Edit grapes<br></td></tr></tbody></table><br></div>","plain_body":"76646015181001122572Spapayapension\nKILLNewJayasankarshenoi2020-07-26 07:11:02Edit grapes","public":false,"attachments":[],"audit_books":1138052982911,"date":"2020-07-26T07:13:59Z","animals":"flowers"},{"books":1138052983031,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"statpapaya":"open","animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":"new"}],"books":1138052982911,"values_books":770550,"timestamp":1595747639,"date":"2020-07-26T07:13:59Z","grapesr_books":4127915143,"fashion":"how are u form","system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"metadata":{"system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","ip_address":"27.62.48.70","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"cpapayaapplem":{}},"animals":"Audit"},{"data_points":[{"books":1139328832112,"fashion":{"thanks":"how are u","source":{"papaya":{},"apple":{},"rel":null}},"fashion_reference_books":null,"type":"flowers","author_books":4127915143,"body":"This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values #770550.\n\nKILLED\n\nfruits fruits,\nfruits Team","html_body":"<div class=\"zd-flowers\" dir=\"auapple\">This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values <a href=\"/orange/valuess/770550\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"values\">#770550</a>.<br><br>KILLED<br>\n\n<span class=\"collapse-signature\"></span><div class=\"signature\"><p dir=\"auapple\">fruits fruits,<br>\nfruits Team</p></div></div>","plain_body":"This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values #770550.\n\nKILLED\n\n\n  fruits fruits,\n\nfruits Team","public":true,"attachments":[],"audit_books":1139328831992,"date":"2020-07-26T07:14:10Z","animals":"flowers"},{"books":1139328832532,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"statpapaya":"solved","animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":"open"},{"books":1139328832612,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"assignee_books":4127915143,"animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":null},{"books":1139328832692,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"group_books":21678429,"animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":null}],"books":1139328831992,"values_books":770550,"timestamp":1595747650,"date":"2020-07-26T07:14:10Z","grapesr_books":4127915143,"fashion":"how are u form","system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"metadata":{"system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","ip_address":"27.62.48.70","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"cpapayaapplem":{}},"animals":"Audit"},{"data_points":[{"books":1139328975052,"fashion":{"thanks":"esuper","source":{"papaya":{"address":"fruitsabcdtaxyajkjjdLAW","name":"fruitsabcdtaxyajkjjdLAW","original_recipients":["fruits-ajkjjdLAWabcdtaxyajkjjdLAW","fruitsabcdtaxyajkjjdLAW"]},"apple":{"name":"ajkjjdLAW Track fruits","address":"fruits-ajkjjdLAWabcdtaxyajkjjdLAW"},"rel":null}},"fashion_reference_books":null,"type":"flowers","author_books":679803769,"body":"##- Please type your reply above this line -##\n\nYou are a follower on this request (545997). Reply apple this esuper apple add an internal note apple the request.\n\n----------------------------------------------\n\ntaxy Activations, Jul 26, 2020, 3:14 AM EDT (private)\n\nFound in POD. Please Cancel with Billing and Carrier\n\n\n**ajkjjdLAW could not be spapayapended with POD, due apple API error or ajkjjdLAW is papayaing another carrier. orange - Please, spapayapend this ajkjjdLAW manually.**\n**ajkjjdLAW Type:** STI-GL300MA\n**abcjbb:** 015181002694066\n**Esuper:** jillturnquist5abcdabcdajkjjdLAW\n**ajkjjdLAW Plan:** Basic\n**Spapayapension Type:** ajkjjdLAW_cancel\n\n--------------------------------\nThis esuper is a ajkjjdLAW papaya taxy fruits.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n[YDEK80-QK99]","html_body":"<div class=\"zd-flowers\" dir=\"auapple\"><p dir=\"auapple\">##- Please type your reply above this line -##</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">You are a follower on this request (545997). Reply apple this esuper apple add an internal note apple the request.</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">----------------------------------------------</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">taxy Activations, Jul 26, 2020, 3:14 AM EDT (private)</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">Found in POD. Please Cancel with Billing and Carrier</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">**ajkjjdLAW could not be spapayapended with POD, due apple API error or ajkjjdLAW is papayaing another carrier. orange - Please, spapayapend this ajkjjdLAW manually.**\n<br>**ajkjjdLAW Type:** STI-GL300MA\n<br>**abcjbb:** 015181002694066\n<br>**Esuper:** <a href=\"superapple:jillturnquist5abcdabcdajkjjdLAW\" rel=\"noreferrer\">jillturnquist5abcdabcdajkjjdLAW</a>\n<br>**ajkjjdLAW Plan:** Basic\n<br>**Spapayapension Type:** ajkjjdLAW_cancel</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">--------------------------------\n<br>This esuper is a ajkjjdLAW papaya taxy fruits.</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">[YDEK80-QK99]</p></div>","plain_body":"##- Please type your reply above this line -## \n\n You are a follower on this request (545997). Reply apple this esuper apple add an internal note apple the request. \n\n ---------------------------------------------- \n\n taxy Activations, Jul 26, 2020, 3:14 AM EDT (private) \n\n Found in POD. Please Cancel with Billing and Carrier \n\n **ajkjjdLAW could not be spapayapended with POD, due apple API error or ajkjjdLAW is papayaing another carrier. orange - Please, spapayapend this ajkjjdLAW manually.**\n\n**ajkjjdLAW Type:** STI-GL300MA\n\n**abcjbb:** 015181002694066\n\n**Esuper:** jillturnquist5abcdabcdajkjjdLAW\n\n**ajkjjdLAW Plan:** Basic\n\n**Spapayapension Type:** ajkjjdLAW_cancel \n\n --------------------------------\n\nThis esuper is a ajkjjdLAW papaya taxy fruits. \n\n [YDEK80-QK99]","public":true,"attachments":[],"audit_books":1139328974972,"date":"2020-07-26T07:14:37Z","animals":"flowers"},{"books":1139328975092,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"subject":"ajkjjdLAW ajkjjdLAW Spapayapend Failed","animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328975112,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"requester_books":679803769,"animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328975132,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"locale_books":"1","animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328975152,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"statpapaya":"new","animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328975172,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"priority":null,"animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328975192,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"type":null,"animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328975212,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"tags":["activations","fruits"],"added_tags":["activations","fruits"],"removed_tags":[],"animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328975232,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"cpapayaapplem_values_fields":{"360018319471":"activations"},"animals":"orange"},{"books":1139328975252,"fashion":"Rule","fashion_reference_books":360131824351,"tags":["activations","new_activation","fruits"],"added_tags":["new_activation"],"removed_tags":[],"rel":"trigger","revision_books":1,"animals":"Change"},{"books":1139328975272,"fashion":"Rule","fashion_reference_books":360157768991,"tags":["activations","new_activation"],"added_tags":[],"removed_tags":["fruits"],"rel":"trigger","revision_books":3,"animals":"Change"}],"books":1139328974972,"values_books":770560,"timestamp":1595747677,"date":"2020-07-26T07:14:37Z","grapesr_books":679803769,"fashion":"super","system":{"client":"ajkjjdLAW superer","gas":"Boardman, OR, United States","latitude":45.8491,"longitude":-119.7143},"metadata":{"system":{"message_books":"<YDEK80QK99_5f1d2d5811742_534d65c02082265_sprutabcdajkjjdLAWajkjjdLAW>","client":"ajkjjdLAW superer","ip_address":"10.219.89.225","raw_esuper_booksentifier":"562885/c1a080cd-9573-4025-b7ff-ca66a4ccda99.eml","json_esuper_booksentifier":"562885/c1a080cd-9573-4025-b7ff-ca66a4ccda99.json","machine_generated":true,"gas":"Boardman, OR, United States","latitude":45.8491,"longitude":-119.7143},"cpapayaapplem":{},"flags":[4],"flags_options":{"4":{"trpapayated":false}},"trpapayated":false,"spapayapension_type_books":null},"animals":"Audit"},{"data_points":[{"books":1139328996232,"fashion":{"thanks":"how are u","source":{"papaya":{},"apple":{},"rel":null}},"fashion_reference_books":null,"type":"flowers","author_books":4127915143,"html_body":"<div class=\"zd-flowers\" dir=\"auapple\"><table wbooksth=\"100%\"><tbody><tr><td>76647</td><td>015181000462250</td><td>Spapayapension</td><td><br></td><td>KILL</td><td>New</td><td>Jayasankarshenoi</td><td>2020-07-26 07:11:42</td><td>Edit grapes<br></td></tr></tbody></table><br></div>","plain_body":"76647015181000462250Spapayapension\nKILLNewJayasankarshenoi2020-07-26 07:11:42Edit grapes","public":false,"attachments":[],"audit_books":1139328996152,"date":"2020-07-26T07:14:41Z","animals":"flowers"},{"books":1139328996472,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"statpapaya":"open","animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":"new"}],"books":1139328996152,"values_books":770551,"timestamp":1595747681,"date":"2020-07-26T07:14:41Z","grapesr_books":4127915143,"fashion":"how are u form","system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"metadata":{"system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","ip_address":"27.62.48.70","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"cpapayaapplem":{}},"animals":"Audit"},{"data_points":[{"books":1138053273191,"fashion":{"thanks":"how are u","source":{"papaya":{},"apple":{},"rel":null}},"fashion_reference_books":null,"type":"flowers","author_books":4127915143,"body":"This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values #770551.\n\nKILLED\n\nfruits fruits,\nfruits Team","html_body":"<div class=\"zd-flowers\" dir=\"auapple\">This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values <a href=\"/orange/valuess/770551\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"values\">#770551</a>.<br><br>KILLED<br>\n\n<span class=\"collapse-signature\"></span><div class=\"signature\"><p dir=\"auapple\">fruits fruits,<br>\nfruits Team</p></div></div>","plain_body":"This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values #770551.\n\nKILLED\n\n\n  fruits fruits,\n\nfruits Team","public":true,"attachments":[],"audit_books":1138053273171,"date":"2020-07-26T07:14:53Z","animals":"flowers"},{"books":1138053273491,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"statpapaya":"solved","animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":"open"},{"books":1138053273551,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"assignee_books":4127915143,"animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":null},{"books":1138053273591,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"group_books":21678429,"animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":null}],"books":1138053273171,"values_books":770551,"timestamp":1595747692,"date":"2020-07-26T07:14:52Z","grapesr_books":4127915143,"fashion":"how are u form","system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"metadata":{"system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","ip_address":"27.62.48.70","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"cpapayaapplem":{}},"animals":"Audit"},{"data_points":[{"books":1139329175332,"fashion":{"thanks":"how are u","source":{"papaya":{},"apple":{},"rel":null}},"fashion_reference_books":null,"type":"flowers","author_books":4127915143,"body":"76648 860599001721083 Spapayapension KILL New Jayasankarshenoi 2020-07-26 07:12:19 Edit grapes","html_body":"<div class=\"zd-flowers\" dir=\"auapple\"><table wbooksth=\"100%\"><tbody><tr><td>76648</td><td>860599001721083</td><td>Spapayapension</td><td><br></td><td>KILL</td><td>New</td><td>Jayasankarshenoi</td><td>2020-07-26 07:12:19</td><td>Edit grapes<br></td></tr></tbody></table><br></div>","plain_body":"76648860599001721083Spapayapension\nKILLNewJayasankarshenoi2020-07-26 07:12:19Edit grapes","public":false,"attachments":[],"audit_books":1139329175212,"date":"2020-07-26T07:15:15Z","animals":"flowers"},{"books":1139329175432,"fashion":"how are u form","fashion_reference_books":null,"statpapaya":"open","animals":"Change","previopapaya_value":"new"}],"books":1139329175212,"values_books":770552,"timestamp":1595747715,"date":"2020-07-26T07:15:15Z","grapesr_books":4127915143,"fashion":"how are u form","system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"metadata":{"system":{"client":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Applehow are uKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36","ip_address":"27.62.48.70","gas":"Chennai, TN, root","latitude":13.0846,"longitude":80.2484},"cpapayaapplem":{}},"animals":"Audit"},{"data_points":[{"books":1138053462151,"fashion":{"thanks":"how are u","source":{"papaya":{},"apple":{},"rel":null}},"fashion_reference_books":null,"type":"flowers","author_books":4127915143,"body":"This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values #770552.\n\nKILLED\n\nfruits fruits,\nfruits Team","html_body":"<div class=\"zd-flowers\" dir=\"auapple\">This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values <a href=\"/orange/valuess/770552\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"values\">#770552</a>.<br><br>KILLED<br>\n\n<span class=\"collapse-signature\"></span><div class=\"signature\"><p dir=\"auapple\">fruits fruits,<br>\nfruits Team</p></div></div>","plain_body":"This is confirmation that your request has been received and has been forwarded apple the Technical fruits Team. Your values books is values #770552.\n\nKILLED\n\n\n  fruits fruits,\n\nfruits Team",Reply apple this esuper apple add an internal note apple the request.\n\n----------------------------------------------\n\ntaxy Activations, Jul 26, 2020, 3:15 AM EDT (private)\n\nFound in POD. Please Cancel with Billing and Carrier\n\n\n**ajkjjdLAW could not be spapayapended with POD, due apple API error or ajkjjdLAW is papayaing another carrier. orange - Please, spapayapend this ajkjjdLAW manually.**\n**ajkjjdLAW Type:** STI-GL300MA\n**abcjbb:** 015181002759042\n**Esuper:** cirena62abcdhotsuperajkjjdLAW\n**ajkjjdLAW Plan:** Basic\n**Spapayapension Type:** ajkjjdLAW_cancel\n\n--------------------------------\nThis esuper is a ajkjjdLAW papaya taxy fruits.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n[93WOVD-Y62X]","html_body":"<div class=\"zd-flowers\" dir=\"auapple\"><p dir=\"auapple\">##- Please type your reply above this line -##</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">You are a follower on this request (545995). Reply apple this esuper apple add an internal note apple the request.</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">----------------------------------------------</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">taxy Activations, Jul 26, 2020, 3:15 AM EDT (private)</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">Found in POD. Please Cancel with Billing and Carrier</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">**ajkjjdLAW could not be spapayapended with POD, due apple API error or ajkjjdLAW is papayaing another carrier. orange - Please, spapayapend this ajkjjdLAW manually.**\n<br>**ajkjjdLAW Type:** STI-GL300MA\n<br>**abcjbb:** 015181002759042\n<br>**Esuper:** <a href=\"superapple:cirena62abcdhotsuperajkjjdLAW\" rel=\"noreferrer\">cirena62abcdhotsuperajkjjdLAW</a>\n<br>**ajkjjdLAW Plan:** Basic\n<br>**Spapayapension Type:** ajkjjdLAW_cancel</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">--------------------------------\n<br>This esuper is a ajkjjdLAW papaya taxy fruits.</p>\n\n<p dir=\"auapple\">[93WOVD-Y62X]</p></div>","plain_body":"##- Please type your reply above this line -## \n\n You are a follower on this request (545995). Reply apple this esuper apple add an internal note apple the request. \n\n ---------------------------------------------- \n\n taxy Activations, Jul 26, 2020, 3:15 AM EDT (private) \n\n Found in POD. Please Cancel with Billing and Carrier \n\n **ajkjjdLAW could not be spapayapended with POD, due apple API error or ajkjjdLAW is papayaing another carrier. orange - Please, spapayapend this ajkjjdLAW manually.**\n\n**ajkjjdLAW Type:** STI-GL300MA\n\n**abcjbb:** 015181002759042\n\n**Esuper:** cirena62abcdhotsuperajkjjdLAW\n\n**ajkjjdLAW Plan:** Basic\n\n**Spapayapension Type:** ajkjjdLAW_cancel \n\n --------------------------------\n\nThis esuper is a ajkjjdLAW papaya taxy fruits. \n\n [93WOVD-Y62X]","public":true,"attachments":[],"audit_books":1138053591851,"date":"2020-07-26T07:15:50Z","animals":"flowers"},{"books":1138053591931,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"subject":"ajkjjdLAW ajkjjdLAW Spapayapend Failed","animals":"orange"},{"books":1138053591971,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"requester_books":679803769,"animals":"orange"},{"books":1138053591991,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"locale_books":"1","animals":"orange"},{"books":1138053592011,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"statpapaya":"new","animals":"orange"},{"books":1138053592031,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"priority":null,"animals":"orange"},{"books":1138053592051,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"type":null,"animals":"orange"},{"books":1138053592071,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"tags":["activations","fruits"],"added_tags":["activations","fruits"],"removed_tags":[],"animals":"orange"},{"books":1138053592111,"fashion":"super","fashion_reference_books":null,"cpapayaapplem_values_fields":{"360018319471":"activations"},"animals":"orange"},{"books":1138053592151,"fashion":"Rule","fashion_reference_books":360131824351,"tags":["activations","new_activation","fruits"],"added_tags":["new_activation"],"removed_tags":[],"rel":"trigger","revision_books":1,"animals":"Change"},{"books":1138053592171,"fashion":"Rule","fashion_reference_books":360157768991,"tags":["activations","new_activation"],"added_tags":[],"removed_tags":["fruits"],"rel":"trigger","revision_books":3,"animals":"Change"}],"books":1138053591851,');
```

Comment: I tried to run the statements here its running without error, may be db settings.

Comment: @JagaSrik What change should I make in DB settings so that I can insert the data?

Comment: im not very sure but you should check about CHARACTER SET , here is a reference link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862717/why-i-cant-save-a-long-text-on-my-mysql-database

Comment: @JagaSrik checked CHARACTER SET. But no effect.

Comment: LONGTEXT also depends on the maximum packet size allowed set both at client and server in MySQL it is 1GB, you should give it a try and check what's set in your Db, mostly this might be the cause in Maria db.

Comment: I tried both example statements on MariaDB 10.4 installation and they work fine.

Comment: can you try to insert the following data for 'details' column:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12bjUelafea2lXhAUJuI6gfdfVi_fk3g5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you modify it and give it as an insert statement would be better, it takes lot of time to just modify it to pass syntax check.

Comment: @geethuth i have modified the google text by replacing all special characters to just chars just to save some time,  it is inserting to the table perfectly, no errors at all.

Comment: Based on your comment, checked the data again. The issue was with single quote. So whenever a single quote is coming, it considers as a column entry. Thanks @JagaSrik. If you post it as an answer, I will definitely mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may ***not exactly answer*** your question but may help a little, i want to show you what i have tried, it is working perfectly fine here, i have modified the file in google drive which you have given  by replacing all special characters to just chars just to *save* some time, it is inserting to the table perfectly, no errors at all.

I would recommend you check `Max_allowed_packet` parameter that you can set it upto 1GB. [link.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/longtext/#:%7E:text=Each%20LONGTEXT%20value%20is%20stored,JSON%20Data%20Type%20for%20details.)

*"The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the client/server protocol and available memory"*

Please check [this.](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/max_allowed_packet/)

Here is the more details to it from reference guide.
[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html#:~:text=The%20largest%20possible%20packet%20that,error%20and%20closes%20the%20connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html#:%7E:text=The%20largest%20possible%20packet%20that,error%20and%20closes%20the%20connection).

here is the [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12bjUelafea2lXhAUJuI6gfdfVi_fk3g5/view?usp=sharing) i used to create insert statements, here is the snapshot of the inserted record and its length, it is working fine here.

[image]

Comment: @JayaSrik Its really helped and I can insert the data. Thanks

Comment: I have posted one issue related to the inserted data in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251979/json-issue-uncaught-typeerrorcannot-read-property-length-of-undefined can anybody help?

Comment: @geethuth, i wish i could help but i dont have idea on jquery or ajax

Comment: glad to hear @JagaSrik